# HighCharts dual x-axis with percent and date

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a requirement to display completion percentage on a bar chart with the start date for each of those project as line chart.


Now, for achieving this I have created a chart with dual y-axis. 
1 - axis-1 shows progress with bar-chart. With max: 100 - avoid displaying values > 100.
2 - axis-2 shows start dates with a line chart


With this set up, I expect the bar to go all the way to the end when value is 100 and the secondary axis to adjust with in it. Instead the bar stops at about 3/4 of the way and line chart actually plots point beyond bar chart's 100%.

 [Following jsfiddle would display the prominently.](https://jsfiddle.net/pkt_tri/mup6vL8d/)

```
var completionChart = $('#Chart').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Project QUAL Status - SD/uSD'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: window.xCategories,
            crosshair: true
        },
        yAxis: [{
            title: {
                text: '% Completion'
            },
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            gridLineWidth: 0
        }, {
            "title": {
                "text": "Start Date"
            },
            type: 'datetime',
            opposite: true
        }],
        tooltip: {
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,1)',
            borderRadius: 10,
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: '#000000',
            useHTML: true,
            positioner: function () {
                return { y: 317 };
            },
            shared: false,
            style: {
                padding: 5
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                groupPadding: 0
            },
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    align: 'left',
                    overflow: 'none',
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                    },
                    formatter: function () {
                        if (this.y <= 100)
                            return Math.round(this.y) + '%';
                    }
                },
                cursor: 'pointer'
            }
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            index: 0,
            name: 'Completion %',
            data: completionpercent,
            showInLegend: false,
            type: 'bar'
        }, {
            data: startDate,
            type: 'spline',
            name: 'Start Date',
            connectNulls: true,
            color: '#2F4367',
            lineWidth: 3,
            yAxis: 1,
            index: 1,
        }]
    });
```

The width of the chart is set and I can not change it without affecting the overall design of the application. Changing the width does help sometimes, but I want a solution that does not depend on the chart width to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `alignTicks` property to `false` in order to achieve this.

Reference:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.alignTicks

Comment: Thanks again jlbriggs. Works perfectly now.